# Difference between objects in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I am trying to find the difference between the elements in the complex array.

I have array list as follows:

```
[
    [{
        id: 123,
        list: [{
            name: "Vimal",
            status: "Pass"
        }, {
            name: "Selvam",
            status: "Pass"
        }]
    }],
    [{
        id: 124,
        list: [{
            name: "Vimal",
            status: "Pass"
        }, {
            name: "Selvam",
            status: "Fail"
        }, {
            name: "Raj",
            status: "Pass"
        }]
    }]
]
```

I would like to get the difference between the `list` as follows:

```
[{
    id: 123,
    list: [{
        name: "Selvam",
        status: "Pass"
    }]
}, {
    id: 124,
    list: [{
        name: "Selvam",
        status: "Fail"
    }, {
        name: "Raj",
        status: "Pass"
    }]
}]
```

I was thinking to loop each element and compare with the adjacent element, then store the differences into the temporary variable. But that sounds too cumbersome approach. I just wanted your opinion on how do I change my way of looking this problem. Pointers would be more helpful. Otherwise, is there any library which could solve this problem easily?

**Edit1**:
Please note that the list will always not a length of 2. The size is dynamic. And the comparison should happen between all elements.

Comment: Does it matter if a difference is flagged when they're simply out of order?

Comment: @BradBumbalough: It doesn't matter

Comment: Awesome! and are you wanting to know *what* changed, or just that it changed?

Comment: What are all changed makes more sense to me

Comment: I think this is probably the clearest explanation of how to approach this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @BradBumbalough : interesting one. I'll give a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the difference you will need the ***intersection*** of the two objects.

In your case, you need to know what is different first. Then you can take that and use it to remove properties to know the ***symmetric difference***.

This is a very complex problem, because comparing arrays if an ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)***. In my case below, I just compared the JSON values. Which is convenient for your problem, but it is not advised for a more complicated object array.

***Note:*** I don't know why you chose to wrap your objects inside the array without a nested array? I removed the brackets to simplify the logic. See the changed JSON. You can easily add this back into the logic of need be.

```js
var dataArr = getSampleData();
var intersectObj = findObjectIntersection(dataArr[0], dataArr[1], {});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(intersectObj, null, 4) + '</pre>';

// Iterate over all keys and find similar key-values.
function findObjectIntersection(obj1, obj2, obj3) {
  var keys1 = Object.keys(obj1); // Object 1 keys
  var keys2 = Object.keys(obj2); // Object 2 keys
  var keysL = keys1.length > keys2.length ? keys1 : keys2;
  var keysS = keysL === keys1 ? keys2 : keys1;
  var keysD = keysL.filter(function(key) {
    return keysS.indexOf(key) > -1;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < keysD.length; i++) {
    var currKey = keysD[i];
    var val1 = obj1[currKey];
    var val2 = obj2[currKey];

    if (isValue(val1) && isValue(val2)) {
      if (val1 === val2) {
        obj3[currKey] = val1;
      }
    } else if (isArray(val1) && isArray(val2)) {
      obj3[currKey] = findArrayIntersectionSimple(val1, val2, []);
    }
  }
  return obj3;
}

// Only compare values by JSON.
function findArrayIntersectionSimple(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
  var arrL = arr1.length > arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
  var arrS = arrL === arr1 ? arr2 : arr1;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrL.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arrS.length; j++) {
      var val1 = JSON.stringify(arrL[i]);
      var val2 = JSON.stringify(arrS[j]);
      if (val1 === val2) {
        arr3.push(arrL[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr3;
}

function isFunction(obj) {
  return {}.toString.apply(obj) === '[object Function]';
}

function isArray(obj) {
  return {}.toString.apply(obj) === '[object Array]';
}

function isObject(obj) {
  return {}.toString.apply(obj) === '[object Object]';
}

function isValue(obj) {
  return !isObject(obj) && !isArray(obj);
}

function getSampleData() {
  return [{
    id: 123,
    list: [{
      name: "Vimal",
      status: "Pass"
    }, {
      name: "Selvam",
      status: "Pass"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 124,
    list: [{
      name: "Vimal",
      status: "Pass"
    }, {
      name: "Selvam",
      status: "Fail"
    }, {
      name: "Raj",
      status: "Pass"
    }]
  }];
}
```

Comment: I guess I didn't communicate properly. You assumed that the list will always be length of 2. But in my case the length will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mr. Polywhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40677966/1218980) says, you want to get the symmetric difference between two arrays.

As it so happens, Lodash has a utility function for that: [`xorWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#xorWith).

Here's a usage example:

```
var symmetricDifference = _.xorWith(array1, array2, comparisonFn);
```

In this example, `xorWith()` is comparing the values of `array1` and `array2` using the `comparisonFn` function.

Since the values of your arrays are objects, you'll need to use a comparison function that deeply checks objects for equality. Lodash has just such a comparison function: [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#isEqual).

So, for your use case, you may get the symmetric difference between your two lists (let's call them `list1` and `list2`) with something like this code:

```
var symmetricDifference = _.xorWith(list1, list2, _.isEqual);
```

Comment: I made an edit to my question. I don't want to compare two array, I would like to compare between elements.